# How to display members of two selected members in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am having a brain melt. I'm a C# newbie and I can't seem to figure out the best way to go about this.

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="360" Margin="66,55,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="623" ItemsSource="{Binding COSPVM}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="GridView1">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Time Stamp" DisplayMemberBinding= "{Binding Path=TimeStamp}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="COSP %" DisplayMemberBinding= "{Binding Path=COSP}"/>
                        
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Above is my XAML code for a ListView with two columns. The one I want to focus on is the one showing a column of dates "Time Stamp". The member is within the list COSPVM.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Time Stamp" DisplayMemberBinding= "{Binding Path=TimeStamp}"/>
```

As the title suggests, I want the user to be able to select two dates in the ListView and have the ListView only display the items between those two dates. What is the best way to go about it? Do I make a combobox or have the user input manually some dates and somehow databind that back to my background code? I have a hard time wrapping my brain around this.

I've thought about making a ComboBox - separate, with just the Dates, where you can pick a date or two and have it DataBind those dates back to the code and then somehow make a method for removing the dates before and after. Still, even that I have a hard time wrapping my brain around.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like more of an opinionated design question but I'll give it my best shot.

Typically when filtering a grid by a date column, the user interface will offer two text boxes (and often a calendar tool for each) above the grid for the user to select the start and end date of the filter, + a "filter" button.

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't want the user to be able to select arbitrary dates, you want specifically dates within the grid.

In that case, I would use 2 additional columns with radio buttons in them as start/end and a button to apply the filter like so:
[image: screenshot of example grid]

Comment: Many thank you for your comment! But I have to admit this solution wouldn't work since the files the program is loading have thousands of Time Stamps, having to go and press the two dates hundreds of rows apart is less than ideal.